# Не работает Data Binding в Ionic, Angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic

В чём может быть проблема? При импорте объекта из `LocaleProvider` могу вывести содержимое внутри любого `.ts` файла, но вывести содержимое на страницу не получается.

Код прилагается:

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { LocaleProvider } from '../../providers/localize';


@Component({
   templateUrl: 'signin.html'
})

export class SigninPage {

language: any = {};

constructor(platform: Platform, public locale: LocaleProvider) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.language = this.locale.getLocale();
        console.log(this.language.ru.translate);       // работает
    });
}
```

**.html (для signinPage)**

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
        {{language.ru.translate}}   // не работает
    </ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: попробуйте language?.ru?.translate

Comment: Спасибо. Так работает. А что значит такая запись?

Comment: это проверка на наличие свойства